# use of XmlAttribute() to retrieve in C# visual2005

Tags: .net, xml, database, xml-serialization, c#-2.0

I'm trying to do something, that may be extremely simple so please bear with me, I just want to get an Attribute from an XML file into a string in my C# code. here's what I have:

XML:

```
<MonitorResponseRecord Enabled="false" DisplayName="ValveFailureAtCentralPosition">
        <ExpressionMonitor>
        <AlarmName>Valve_Position_Fault</AlarmName>
            <Parameter> Sensor Position = {X}</Parameter>
        </ExpressionMonitor>
</MonitorResponseRecord>
<MonitorResponseRecord ...  ... ...>
... ...
... ... and so on about 1600 times.
```

C#:

```
[Selrializable]
[XmlType("Alarm")]  
public class AlarmDefinition
    {
        public AlarmDefinition() {}
        public AlarmDefinition Clone()
        {
            AlarmDefinition clone = new AlarmDefinition();
            clone.DisplayName = DisplayName;
                          clone.Category = Category;
        clone.Color = Color;
        clone.Description = Description;
                          return clone;

                 }

    [XmlAttribute( ??????????? )] public string DisplayName = "";
```

so does anyone know what I would need in the '???????????' section?
I've tried:

```
[XmlAttribute("MonitorResponseRecord",AttributeName = "DisplayName")] public string DisplayName = "";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the attribute is `@DisplayName`, that is either just:

```
[XmlAttribute]
public string DisplayName = "";
```

or, more explicitly:

```
[XmlAttribute("DisplayName")]
public string DisplayName = "";
```

(although a property would be preferable to a public field, IMO)

The real problem seems to be the root name; it that is the outermost part of the xml document, you will need:

```
[XmlRoot("MonitorResponseRecord")]
public class AlarmDefinition {...}
```

Comment: I should have made myself abit more clear, there are other items in the AlarmDefinition class based on some other parameters, I've updated the C# and XML codes

Comment: @DarthSheldon the xml in your answer is not a well-formed document; thus it is impossible to say what is the root. Can you be more specific? there is no way we can repro anything with what you have posted, as XmlSerializer **will not work with that**. However, my statement about `[XmlAttribute]` still stands - that is the appropriate annotation to fit your data.

Comment: I tried the [XmlRoot("MonitorResponseRecord")]  Idea, but it doesn't seem to work, is there something else I must add??